# If NSTimer does not work when an iOS app is in the background, how can I get my app to wake up periodically?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nstimer

I have noticed that some apps e.g. Skype run in the background.
I would like to have my app run in the background also, waking up every 1 seconds to update some data and then going to sleep again.
How can I do this?
I gather that NSTimer's do not work in the background.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. Voice-over-IP apps get a special exception for this, basically the system manages a network socket for them and wakes them up if there's data. There's no way to do the same with a timer.

By the way, waking your app every second, your battery wouldn't last half a day.

Comment: You can actually for certain types of applications.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24

The section on Long running background tasks apply.
Only saw the date now. Old thread, but here is the info for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

See [Executing Code in the Background](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use push notifications to push information to the app (like the Facebook or Skype app).  See [this documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1) from Apple on how to use push notifications.

Not every second though, that would drain the battery.  Other than that, there isn't really a way unless you are running a VoIP app.